# CheckAll for the checkbox disabled but do not disable childs checkbox

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I'm currently working with Primefaces, I have a datatable component and I render some records. When I edit inline-edit some records, I want to avoid the customer to click at the header checkbox to select all checkboxes, I like the customer to check the boxes that he wants to use manually.

I'm able to use the datatable configuration:

```
<composite:datatable disabledSelection="#{bean.disabledSelection}">
```

If this condition is true, all my checkboxes are disabled, but I just need that the one located at the THead is disabled, like this screen:

[image: The header checkbox is disabled, but I can check the childs]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

In chrome you could check the id of the component and then disable it programatically.

```
UIComponent component = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(topSelectionId);
if(component!=null && component instanceof SelectOneMenu) {
         ((SelectOneMenu) component).setDisabled(true);
}
```